# Factorize a Matrix without Any Memory Allocations in Julia

Tags: performance, memory, julia, allocation

Julia supports in place factorization of matrices (for some factorizations).
I wonder if one could also eliminate any allocation of memory inside the function.

For instance, is there a way to apply a Cholesky factorization on a matrix with no *hidden* memory allocation?

Comment: You mean something like a generator?

Comment: I mean something like low level API which allows pre defining the buffers for the task.

Comment: note that if your matrices are bigger than ~10x10 the allocation overhead will be minimal

Answer (score 3):

Non allocating LAPACK functions have bindings in Julia. They are documented in [Julia Documentation - Linear Algebra - LAPACK Functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LAPACK-functions).

---

The Cholesky factorization `cholesky!(A)` overwrites `A` and does allocate a fixed small amount of memory, whereas `cholesky(A)` does allocate a larger amount. Here, allocations (bytes) do grow quadratically with the size of `A`.

```
let n = 1000; M = rand(n,n); B = transpose(M)*M
    cholesky(B)
    @time cholesky(B)
    # 0.023478 seconds (5 allocations: 7.630 MiB)
end
```

vs

```
let n = 1000; M = rand(n,n); B = transpose(M)*M
    cholesky!(copy(B))
    @time cholesky!(B)
    # 0.021360 seconds (3 allocations: 80 bytes)
end
```

Performance differences are small as pointed out by Oscar Smith.

Comment: Could you give the code for the SVD, and Cholesky? For instance, I don't see where are the buffers in `pstrf!`.

Comment: I don't see why you think those functions are non allocating. It seems they can operate in place, but are they guaranteed to not allocate?

Comment: Unfortunately, Julia does not have an allocation free factorization. However, some modifications to [`gesdd!`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/742b9abb4dd4621b667ec5bb3434b8b3602f96fd/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/src/lapack.jl#L1630) could do the trick. This question has also been discussed in the [Julia discourse forum](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/in-place-svd/60567/4)